# Tooltip position on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have simple image preview on `hover`.

jQuery

```
jQuery('img').hover(
    function(){
        jQuery('body').append('<div id="image_preview"><img src="'+ jQuery(this).attr('src') +'" alt="Image preview" /></div>');
        jQuery('.camera_info img').mousemove(
            function(event){
                jQuery('#image_preview').css('top', (event.pageY - 10) + 'px').css('left', (event.pageX + 30) + 'px').fadeIn('normal');
            }
        );
    },
    function(){
        jQuery('#image_preview').remove();
    }
);
```

CSS:

```
#image_preview {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    display: none;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

The problem is that if the image is too close to the side of the browser it shows after it like here:
[image]

I tried to play with right position, but with no luck... Can someone help me on this problem?

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: There's no point re-inventing the wheel; use [qtip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/), problem solved.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If they use their own plug-in on the page you've linked, it's not handling OP's issue : (.

Comment: It does, check the demos and then 'collision detection'

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Nope, OP want's to see the whole image, when it appears near to the edge of the viewport.

Comment: I understand that. qTip has this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I was using to keep an element's top and bottom within the viewable area of a browser -- in my case, I didn't have to worry about handling an element's left/right coordinate, but the below code could be adjusted to handle that as well.

The function takes an HTMLElement as an argument, ie return value of `$('#someid').get(0)` or `document.getElementById('someid')`  and uses jQuery throughout.

```
function moveIntoView (elem)
{
    var w$ = $(window),
      elem$ = $(elem),
      docViewTop = w$.scrollTop(),
      docViewBottom = docViewTop + w$.height(),
      elTop = elem$.offset().top,
      elBottom = elTop + elem$.height();
    //  element top is lower than top of document in view
    //  and element bottom is higher than bottom of document in view, so nothing to do
    if( ((docViewTop <= elTop) && (docViewBottom >= elBottom)))
       return;

    elem$.css("top", parseInt(elem$.css("top")) - (elBottom - docViewBottom));
}
```